# How to extend a Control in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I want to extend the default dropdown with some functionality. The custom dropdown should behave like a default dropdown in the `.xaml` file, so it should be possible to add items to it.

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work like in WPF. That's my approach:

**MainWindow.xaml:** (added the namespace)

```
<local:myCustomDropDown>
  <DropDownItem>1</DropDownItem>
  <DropDownItem>2</DropDownItem>
</local:myCustomDropDown>
```

**myCustomDropDown.xaml:**

```
<DropDown xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          x:Class="AvaloniaApplication2.myCustomDropDown">
</DropDown>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public class myCustomDropDown : DropDown
{
    public myCustomDropDown()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }
}
```

This seems to compile without errors or warnings, but the control does not show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also apply DropDown's control styles. You can do that by changing the style key like this: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/353c24b8abdeaae2a1c543665ef46c2161573e9f/src/Avalonia.Controls/UserControl.cs#L31
:

```cs
public class UserControl : ContentControl, IStyleable
{
        Type IStyleable.StyleKey => typeof(ContentControl);
```

Comment: Link only answer! Copy relevant parts and post them as a part of your answer instead of just pointing to some other web location. For more information read [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad)

Comment: @kekekeks in light of some of the referenced myget repositories going down (and are no longer accessible) can you please elucidate your answer? I get that in the GitHub world, linking 20 projects deep is "acceptable" .. but, one can no longer build the source code for AvalonStudio because one of the F# Test projects requires a reference that no longer exists. Hence why, on StackExchange *EVERYONE* points at link only answers and screams what Mateusz said. Because referenced links go down, and the answer is no more; kinda like github projects with broken link dependencies in the covid epoch. :P